# When a variable has space in it , the div is not collapsable

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nvx4tkLt/8/

I noticied that if the variable has got space in it , the div is not collapsable .

For example IN the jsfiddle , if you click on Brothers Home the div is not collapsable .

When clciked on the div this is the code that is being executed

```
$(document).on('click', '.lielement', function() {
    var locationname = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).find('.restListings').length)
    $(this).find('.restListings').remove()
    else
    displayingRestaurantsForLabel(locationname);
});
function displayingRestaurantsForLabel(locationname)
{
    showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(restaurantsbylocation,locationname);
}
function showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(response, locationname) {
    var responsedata = JSON.stringify(response);
    $("#restmenu").find('.restListings').remove();
    var ulhtml = $('<ul class="restListings"></ul>');
    var divhtml = $('<div class="inner-intit"><sub class="sub">Yours Favorite Restaurant</sub></div>');
    divhtml.append('<br>');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        divhtml.append('<li class="grayOut-Rest innerChild"><h6> '+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6></li>');
        existingrestaurants.push(response[i].vendor_id);
    }
    ulhtml.append(divhtml);
    $("#restmenu").find('#'+locationname.trim()).append(ulhtml);
}
```

Could anybody please let me know whats the issue ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are using the name as id. So the id has a space in it, and that's invalid.

> The id attribute value must begin with a letter in the roman alphabet (a–z or A–Z); this can be followed by any combination of letters (a–z or A–Z), digits (0–9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/

So you should change your id's. You could use the name like you do now, but you should delete all the whitespaces first.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the explanation of the issue .